# Angularjs Table Total with Dropdown change

Tags: angularjs

i am new in Angularjs and have one problem. i load my data from backend and need to calculate a total. Like we can see, i have 06 entries [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1] and a Total would be 0.20.
but if a user change a price my total need to be recalculate, but it doesn't do that. 
Please someone can tell me how to chnage that?

[image]

Comment: can you paste your html and js code would be wonderful

Comment: <td><span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{eigens.zuschlag}}</span> </td>
     <td>
 <select ng-init="price = eigens.price" ng-model="price" ng-change="mySum()" ng-options="value for value in eigens.editprice">
</select>   $scope.mySum = function(){
    console.log('test');
    var myprice = 0;
      angular.forEach($scope.pv, function(pv, i){
        myprice += parseFloat(pv.myprice);
      });
      $scope.result2 = $scope.result + myprice;
  }

Comment: please post the code in a plunkr with its link, the code which you have commented is not formatted properly

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/EFI7yql6u3mxl54CEHYN?p=preview

Comment: i try to generate a dummy dataset and that is how its looking

Answer (score 0):

Please find below updated working solution!!!

```js
var app = angular.module('example', []);

app.controller('exampleCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = [
      {
          "Name": "Initiative",
          "Price": 0.1,
          "Prices": [0.0, 0.1, -0.1]   //For my Dropdowliste
      },
      {
          "Name": "Believe",
          "Price": 0.1,
          "Prices": [0.0, 0.1, -0.1]   //For my Dropdowliste
      },
      {
          "Name": "Tendance",
          "Price": 0.1,
          "Prices": [0.0, 0.1, -0.1]   //For my Dropdowliste
      },
      {
          "Name": "Reach",
          "Price": 0.1,
          "Prices": [0.0, 0.1, -0.1]  //For my Dropdowliste
      },
        {
            "Name": "Head",
            "Price": 0.1,
            "Prices": [0.0, 0.1, -0.1]   //For my Dropdowliste
        }
    ];


    function getTotalResult() {

        var runningSalesTotal = 0.0;

        angular.forEach($scope.test, function (data) {
            runningSalesTotal += parseFloat(data.Price);
        });

        return runningSalesTotal;
    }

    $scope.mySum = function () {        
        $scope.result = getTotalResult();
    }

    $scope.mySum();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="example">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="table">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Personalnummer</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="eigens in test" ng-click="eineFunktion(eigens)">
                            <td>
                                {{eigens.Name}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{eigens.price}}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select ng-model="eigens.Price" ng-change="mySum()"
                                        ng-options="value for value in eigens.Prices"></select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Summe</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>{{result | currency: '€'}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hallo J-Mean, thanks for your Answer. But you had a same Problem like me, because if you set a value of Initiative to -0.1, a new Total would be 0.3 and that isnt true because 0.5 - 0.1 = 0.4

Comment: You had some miss calculation, 4 entry with 0.1 will have following result i.e. 0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1=0.4 and 1 entry with value -0.1 so final result will be 0.4 -0.1 = 0.3. Please verify !!

Comment: That is true. My explication wasnt true. I would like to have something like if you load a first time this frontend and had total=0.5, now if you select 0 or - 0.1, Total need to be recalculate again with a new in this price column.

Comment: This is happening did you "run code snippet" and checked your requirement. You can observe "Summe" gets updated based on price selection. Please try and let me know..

Comment: I am realy down, that is more than true. Thanks